# Is there a way to securely log into a MacBook Pro without typing a password?

Tags: macbook-pro, password, accessibility

I have a motor disability that at times makes it difficult to type on a laptop keyboard. I am still able to use a MacBook Pro, especially when I connect it to an external keyboard. I normally use touch id to authenticate, but Apple [requires a password](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-touch-id-mchl16fbf90a/mac) to be entered under some circumstances, such as after rebooting.

I don't always have an external keyboard handy, and my organization requires a 15-character password. Is there anything that can be done with software or hardware so I don't have to enter a long password to use the computer? I have a 2019 MBP running Monterey.

**Update**

I reached out to Yubi who told me:

> As of now, there is no way to natively protect a Mac OSX login using
> the Yubikey Bio. The Yubikey 5 series can be set up with a Macbook as
> a Smart Card, but the Yubikey Bio does not support that integration.
> Please note that this integration is a bit technical so please be
> careful to follow the documentation.

I would want biometric protection of the password.

Comment: Check out a [Yubi key token](https://www.yubico.com/)

Comment: Ask for an exception on the 15 character rule, due to medical reasons.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the suggestion. I read more, and it looks like it can't take the place of the initial password on Intel silicon. This could be useful when I next upgrade though.

Comment: That’s too bad.  I was hoping it could solve the issue for you.  Apple has some good Accessibility features, but you can’t use them until you get in to activate them.

Comment: I just had an idea… Take a look at [X-Keys](https://xkeys.com/xk4.html). That model linked has 4 programmable keys and according to the spec sheet, it has 1000 char memory. You could  store your password as a keypress (or a sequence for security)and it should act just like a standard keyboard because it’s an HID device meaning it will work before the OS loads.

Comment: @Allan Interesting. Someone pointed me to the Yubi Bio series, which might do what I want (if it just acts like a keyboard) and requires a fingerprint. I'll give them a call. (Their web form didn't work.) https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-bio-series/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My local IT department and I were not able to find a way for me to log in biometrically to an Intel-based MacBook Pro. I communicated with a Yubi sales representative, who confirmed the Yubi Bio cannot do what I want.

I was able to have my computer switched to use local login, which has less stringent password requirements that network login.